# Azure Unable to load shared library - using nodejs

Tags: node.js, azure

I am having this error on my page.

iisnode encountered an error when processing the request.
HRESULT: 0x2
HTTP status: 500`enter code here`
HTTP reason: Internal Server Error

You are receiving this HTTP 200 response because system.webServer/ii`enter code here`snode/@devErrorsEnabled configuration setting is 'true'.

In addition to the log of stdout and stderr of the node.exe process, consider using debugging and ETW traces to further diagnose the problem.

The last 64k of the output generated by the node.exe process to stdout and stderr is shown below:

node.js:201
        throw e; // process.nextTick error, or 'error' event on first tick
              ^
Error: Unable to load shared library C:\DWASFiles\Sites\leagues\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-sqlserver\lib\sqlserver.node
    at Object..node (module.js:472:11)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
    at require (module.js:370:17)
    at Object. (C:\DWASFiles\Sites\leagues\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\node_modules\node-sqlserver\lib\sql.js:20:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:441:26)
    at Object..js (module.js:459:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:348:31)
    at Function._load (module.js:308:12)

and this is my code for server.js

```
var sql = require('node-sqlserver');
var conn_str = the value of ODBC in Connection Strings;
var http = require('http');
var port = process.env.port;
http.createServer(function(req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.write("start");
res.end("finish");
sql.query(conn_str, "SELECT * FROM GAME_PARTICIPANT", function(err, results) {
    if (err) {
        res.writeHead(500, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
        res.write("Database Error: " + err)
        res.end("");
        return;
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        res.write("ID: " + results[i].PlayerID + " GameID: " + results[i].GameID + " Team: " + results[i].Team + " Confirmed: " + results[i].Confirmed + " RoleID: " + results[i].RoleID);
    }
    res.end("; Done.");
});
}).listen(port);
```

Comment: how did you deploy the node driver?  Might this be close to what you are running into: https://github.com/WindowsAzure/node-sqlserver/issues/51.  If you haven't already, check out this blog post for info and contact for help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlphp/archive/2012/06/08/introducing-the-microsoft-driver-for-node-js-for-sql-server.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this error trying out the driver too.

Turns out, I didn't have all the prerequisites for compiling the `.node` file which seems to happen automatically at deployment time.

What worked for me was to include the pre-compiled `.node` file from the article Jim mentions above (direct link at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29995) and put it in the `node_modules\node-sqlserver\lib` folder alongside the `sql.js` file. Redeploy everything (including the `.node` file) and you should be good to go.

Oh - I remember still seeing an error about not being able to compile the `.node` file, but it seemed to run OK anyway since I'd provided the binary myself.  Go figure...

Comment: Chris, I downloaded the .node file from the location you mentioned and I get the error

Native sqlserver module not found. Did you remember to run node-gyp configure build?

what could be going wrong? the same file works ok on my pc

Comment: I figured I had to use the ia32 version even if I run on 64bit windows.